# addFieldToFilter() 'OR' query on non EAV data doing something odd

Tags: collection, collection-filtering

I am modifying the Magento search results to include matching categories, pages and blog posts (from the free version of Neotheme nBlog).  Whilst the categories and pages are working just fine there is something very odd going on with the blog posts. The posts appear to be stored in a flat, non-EAV, table.

When I do this, searching for "test":

```
$needleSearch = "test";
$posts = Mage::getModel("neotheme_blog/post")
                ->setStoreId($storeId)
                ->getCollection()
                ->addStoreFilter()
                ->addStatusFilter(NeoTheme_Blog_Model_Post::STATUS_ACTIVE)
                ->addPublishFilter()
                ->addFieldToFilter(
                    array(
                        array("attribute"=>"title","like"=>$needleSearch),
                        array("attribute"=>"author","like"=>$needleSearch),
                        array("attribute"=>"summary","like"=>$needleSearch)
                    )
                  ) //OR BIT
                ;
```

The resulting SELECT query ends up with this in the middle:

```
((`title`.`%test%` = '') OR (`author`.`%test%` = '') OR (`summary`.`%test%` = ''))
```

The nested array for the OR works fine for the EAV (categories and pages).

This also produces the same result:

```
            ->addFieldToFilter(
                    array(
                        array("title","like"=>$needleSearch),
                        array("author","like"=>$needleSearch),
                        array("summary","like"=>$needleSearch)
                    )
             )
```

Putting array() around the like bit ends with the SQL query showing

```
...(`title`.`array` = '') OR...
```

A single LIKE works:

```
$posts = Mage::getModel("neotheme_blog/post")
                ->setStoreId($storeId)
                ->getCollection()
                ->addStoreFilter()
                ->addFieldToFilter( 'title', array('like'=>$needleSearch) )
;
```

I was wondering if anyone had any idea of what might be going on? I can't find an override of addFieldToFilter() in the module.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax to combine conditions of **different fields** with OR is:

```
->addFieldToFilter(
    array(
        'title',
        'author',
        'summary'
    ),
    array(
        array('like' => $needleSearch),
        array('like' => $needleSearch),
        array('like' => $needleSearch),
    )
);
```

i.e. to pass an array of fields an and array of conditions. The elements of these arrays with the same keys will be treated as if they were passed as single parameters.

Comment: this works, thanks.  Thought I had also tried this but must have got something wrong. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this?

```
$collection
    ->getSelect()
    ->where("(something like 'abc') OR (something_else LIKE 'doremi')");
```

PS: you should worry about sql injection

Comment: Well done for pointing out the SQL injection aspect.

Comment: This does work also however, I am selecting the answer by fshmengler as that uses the core system and the sql protection therein.